# multi-part form permit sending unfilled params, param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with some required inputs. When I have multi-part set to true and all my field are empty, the submit is done with no value in the params.

```
<form class="simple_form form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid" role="form" novalidate="novalidate" id="new_coupon" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/coupons" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Ssr+XnrLBfHur1C43sIfh3mJihR0MrrLdeubEaJXcoMhrjl7wZcJF4ox+54uQ+ebkg+EZzIVV9X6iLaZSHcNKQ==">
  <div>
    <label class="string required control-label" for="coupon_title"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Titre du bon plan</label>
    <input class="string required form-control" type="text" value="" name="coupon[title]" id="coupon_title"><span class="help-block">doit être rempli(e)</span>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Enregistrer mon bon plan" data-disable-with="Enregistrer mon bon plan">
  </div>
</form>
```

When I remove the enctype attribute, it worked and im not redirected if they are empty.

My params look like this when the enctype is on:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qqLfnvg/qzHcdAYAaKJYyIGal6zkCKllW0ttRoVAba7Bxhi7Q2On17jqrSaYI6DUahyZ36IvRHvUKEDOb2ASBA==", "commit"=>"Enregistrer mon bon plan"}
```

As you can see, the param coupon that I'm sending is missing

Someone understand what should I do to validate my form?

Comment: i did a fetch instead of a require in my controller, it patch the problem for the moment

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug solved in [this PR](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/f2baf7ba76f90d5977abc347fed3a6bb7d32e114). It is fixed in Rack 2.0.0.rc1.